# How to capture close event of the child web page in parent web page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have web page parent and web page child.

When child web page is closed I want some function to be fired in parent web page.

I know that I can catch close event in child web page and sent it to parent, but I don't want to implement it this way.

Is there any event in parent window that can catch or can be fired when child window is closed?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a reference to the child window, you can do:

```
var child = window.open("");
child.addEventListener("unload", function () {
    console.log("child window closed");
});
```